# How to use ffmpeg faststart flag programmatically?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, mp4

I try to convert videos for playback on Android using H264, AAC codecs and mp4 container. Video plays normaly with non-system  players. But system player shows error "Can't play this video".
I found out that the problem is in moov atom, which is writed in the end of the file.
When I use "-movflags +faststart" ffmeg flag to convert video, it plays normal, but when I try to do that programmatically, it gives no result. I use following code:

```
av_dict_set( &dict, "movflags", "faststart", 0 );
ret = avformat_write_header( ofmt_ctx, &dict );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine:

```
av_dict_set( &dict, "movflags", "faststart", 0 );
ret = avformat_write_header( ofmt_ctx, &dict );
```

But problem is not solved. I still can't play converted videos on Android devices.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that this answer is very late, but still, for anyone who might still be facing the same issue: this might be caused by the `AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER` not being set in the audio/video `AVCodecContext`. A lot of guides show that it needs to be set in the `AVFormatContext`, but it needs to be set in the `AVCodecContext` before opening it using `avcodec_open2`.

```
if (format_context->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) {
  video_codec_context->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
}
avcodec_open2(video_codec_context, video_codec, nullptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

Set `url` field of `AVFormatContext` before `avformat_write_header`.

#### Why

I hit same issue today, and I found there is a log when calling `av_write_trailer`:

> Unable to re-open  output file for the second pass (faststart)

In the `movenc.c` implementation, we can see it needs `s->url` to re-open the file:

```c
avio_flush(s->pb);
ret = s->io_open(s, &read_pb, s->url, AVIO_FLAG_READ, NULL);
if (ret < 0) {
    av_log(s, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Unable to re-open %s output file for "
           "the second pass (faststart)\n", s->url);
    goto end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the video is not compatible with your android phone? Try to convert with h264 baseline profile.

Comment: I use baseline profile. I set it by following code: codec->profile = FF_PROFILE_H264_CONSTRAINED_BASELINE; av_dict_set( &opts, "vprofile", "baseline", 0 ); av_opt_set( codec->priv_data, "profile", "baseline", AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN ); avcodec_open2( codec, encoder, &opts); But I still got no result. When I use -vprofile baseline ffmpeg command, it plays on Android. I think that the problem in something else.

Comment: I found out thet the prolem is in h264 encoder, because mpeg4+aac+mp4 works fine.